# React-router link gets escaped on share

Tags: react-router

I'm using `react-router` to handle my routing.

Let's say I want to share a page with a search param :

`http://myshop.localhost:3001/?collection=D%27apr%E8s%20Orelsan`

If I copy/paste this link in my browser, it'll work just fine. Now, if I share it, or copy/paste in anywhere else (a messenger link, a facebook post, whatever), whoever clicks on it will be redirected to

`http://arcadyrecords.localhost:3001/?collection=D%2527apr%25E8s%2520Orelsan`

Therefore messing up my fetching logic.

How can I prevent external links from re-escaping an url that is already escaped ?

Comment: Which version of react router are you using?

Comment: What do you use to encode the url in the first place so that you get `http://myshop.localhost:3001/?collection=D%27apr%E8s%20Orelsan`?

Comment: @c-chavez I'm using the following: 
    "react-route": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",

Comment: For me it looks like an error on the encoding... if I try to decode the url in your example I get an error of a malformed url. Might be the same that facebook or messenger gets so they try to encode the url or something. That part of `%E8s` seems odd...

Comment: @c-chavez i'm pretty sure it's because of "weird" characters, my first URL gets escaped because of an "è" character,

Comment: so how are you encoding those characters? what is the original url before encoding?